# Scale SVG icon in folium map

Tags: folium

I have an SVG icon that I want to have in my Folium map, but it seems that no matter what I try, it will not stop rendering at 12x12px

Here is the relevant code:

```
for _, row in features_gdf.iterrows():
    pt = row.geometry.coords[0]
    pt = tuple(reversed(pt))
    circle_marker = folium.Marker(
        pt,
        icon=folium.DivIcon(html=f"""<div>{open(f'{HERE}/svg/telecom_tower.svg').read()}</div>""")
    ).add_to(m)
```

This works, but every icon renders at 12x12px

I thought I could do it with a `CustomIcon`:

```
for _, row in features_gdf.iterrows():
    pt = row.geometry.coords[0]
    pt = tuple(reversed(pt))
    icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=f'{HERE}/svg/my_icon.svg', icon_size=(24, 24))
    circle_marker = folium.Marker(
        pt,
        icon=icon
    ).add_to(m)
```

How can I make the map render the icons at the correct size?

Comment: This may be an off-topic comment, but can't the target image be enlarged by changing it to a JPG or PNG?